# How can I save image in mongoDB with resizing by using node.js and express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post("/addProducts", (req, res) => {
    const file = req.files.file;
    
    const newImg = file.data;
    const encImg = newImg.toString("base64");

    var image = {
      contentType: req.files.file.mimetype,
      size: req.files.file.size,
      img: Buffer.from(encImg, "base64"),
    };

    productCollection
      .insertOne({ image })
      .then((result) => {
        res.send(result.insertedCount > 0);
      });
  });
```

I'm trying to save an image in MongoDB, but this code is backdated. They are using another npm package. Any help would be appreciated. I do not use a path for sending image.